# Error when connecting to web service which requires certificate

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, webclient, keystore

I'm trying to connect to a web service of a company which gave me 4 certificates in .cert format, I have put these certificates in a keystore and have established Https connecting on my client code

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",ERPGetProperty.erpGetProperty("pathToKeyStore"));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", ERPGetProperty.erpGetProperty("pathToKeyStore"));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS"); 
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory  = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

    URL url = new URL(address);
    HttpsURLConnection con  = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);  
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setUseCaches(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(xml.length()));
    con.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", address);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);

    userPass = username + ":" + password;
    byte[] encodeBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(userPass.getBytes());
    String encode = new String(encodeBytes);
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encode);

    out = con.getOutputStream();

    out.write(b);
```

I always get this exception

```
 10:21:15,591 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) java.net.ConnectException:  Operation timed out

10:21:15,591 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at     java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
10:21:15,591 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
10:21:15,592 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
10:21:15,592 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
10:21:15,593 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
10:21:15,593 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
10:21:15,593 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
10:21:15,594 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
10:21:15,594 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
10:21:15,594 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
10:21:15,595 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
10:21:15,595 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
10:21:15,595 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
10:21:15,596 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
10:21:15,596 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
10:21:15,596 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
10:21:15,597 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
10:21:15,597 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
10:21:15,598 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at hot.com.mhd.erp.action.client.PushStatusClient.pushXML(PushStatusClient.java:492)
10:21:15,598 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at main.com.mhd.erp.sched.StatusPushJob.execute(StatusPushJob.java:73)
10:21:15,598 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
10:21:15,599 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)   at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

And this is this is some of what i get from debug mode before exception is thrown

```
10:21:00,034 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
10:21:00,034 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
10:21:00,035 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
10:21:00,035 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
10:21:00,036 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
10:21:00,036 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
10:21:00,036 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
10:21:00,036 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
10:21:00,037 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
10:21:00,037 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
10:21:00,037 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
10:21:00,037 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
10:21:00,038 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
10:21:00,038 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
10:21:00,038 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
10:21:00,038 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
10:21:00,039 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
10:21:00,039 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
10:21:00,039 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
10:21:00,039 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
10:21:00,040 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

Please help me! I'm running out of time to solve this issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
  10:21:15,591 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) java.net.ConnectException:  Operation timed out
  10:21:15,591 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

You get a connection timeout at the plain socket level already. Please make sure that the server is up and open for connections from outside and that no firewall in between your app and the server is blocking the access. Try with another client to connect to the server to make sure the problem is at your application.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! So that means that exception has nothing to do with the certificates not set up properly? They are all in .cer format and I imported them using my keytool to a keystore I created and I specified the path to it as a System property along with the password. Company says they have their server up and running. Maybe those errors about the cipher suite are causing the issue. I'm using a Mac OS 10.10 to do this. How can I make sure there is no firewall between me and the server? Sorry about the many questions but I'm pretty new with this. Thanks again!

Comment: Check with another client. If it fails too it is the firewall or the server itself. In this case check from another location, as near as possible to the server. If the server is just set up for you it might also be that they forgot to properly test it on their site.